# uuid function undefined despite header file and library inclusion

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Why is `uuid_generate_random` undefined? As far as I know I am including the `uuid` library when compiling.

Any advice whats going wrong?

> me@me-vm:~/Projects/_Tests/test_cba$ make
>   g++ -o res main.cpp -Luuid -std=c++11
>   /tmp/ccRubbJa.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to 'uuid_generate_random'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

Simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <uuid/uuid.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    uuid_t id;
    uuid_generate_random(id);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using wrong command.Use below

> g++ -o res main.cpp -luuid -std=c++11

-L is used to provide location of library

-l is used to provide name library.